# Angular - Using NgControl does not work with writeValue

Tags: angular

I am a custome control with valueAccessor as below

```
constructor( @Self() @Optional() public valueControl: NgControl ) {
    if( valueControl ) {
        valueControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
}

writeValue( values: any ): void {
        if( this.valueControl.control.value) {   // error here because control is undefined
            // Do something 
        }
}
```

I dont understand why the control is undefined when its injected within the constructor. Any help please?

Comment: Has you use your control with ngModel or with a FormControl? BTW:write value receive as argument the value of the control at very initial phase (the variable "values")

Comment: I use this custom control with formControlName property

Comment: In constructor,try `if( this.valueControl ) { this.valueControl.valueAccessor = this;  }` -see the "this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the `valueControl` on the class i.e. via this

```
  // bind this custom component to control value accessor
  constructor(@Self() @Optional() public ngControl: NgControl) {
    this.ngControl && (this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this);
  }
```

Hence `this.ngControl`, `valueControl` in your case, is undefined in your `writeValue` function

Comment: Of course I am doing it. You can see in my post, there is a constructor

Comment: Apologies if the "this" wasn't clear. Thanks Eliseo for clarifying in the comments